# How to prevent LaTeX verbatim environments to be subject to LaTeX-fill-region

Tags: auctex, fill-paragraph

With `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local`, it is possible to declare environments that AUCTeX should consider as verbatim ones.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbatimenv}
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{myverbatimenv}
\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local: ("myverbatimenv")
% End:
```

The problem is, such environments are subject to `LaTeX-fill-region` (`C-c C-q C-r`). Hence, if the whole buffer is selected (`C-x h)` and is filled (`C-c C-q C-r`), the verbatim environment becomes:

```latex
\begin{myverbatimenv}
First verbatim line.  Second verbatim line.
\end{myverbatimenv}
```

whereas I would like:

```latex
\begin{myverbatimenv}
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{myverbatimenv}
```

How to prevent these LaTeX verbatim environments to be subject to `LaTeX-fill-region`?

Comment: How do you define `myverbatimenv`?  Do you use a LaTeX package like `fancyvrb` etc.?

Comment: @ArashEsbati For instance thanks to `fancyvrb`: `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myverbatimenv}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\normalsize}`. Another use case: make use of `alltt` environment from the eponymous package, the latter being loaded, not directly, but by a third party package loaded in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your self-defined verbatim environment to `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`.

Your modified example would look like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
This text
just shows
that LaTeX-fill-region does something.
\begin{myverbatimenv}
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{myverbatimenv}
\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local: ("myverbatimenv")
% eval: (setq-local LaTeX-indent-environment-list (cons '("myverbatimenv" current-indentation) (default-value 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list)))
% End:
```

Note the third paragraph in the doc string of `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`:

> `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` is a variable defined in ‘latex.el’.
>   Its value is shown below.
>
> Documentation:
>   Alist of environments with special indentation.
>   The second element in each entry is the function to calculate the
>   indentation level in columns.
>
> **Environments present in this list are not filled by filling
>   functions, see `LaTeX-fill-region-as-paragraph`.**

Comment: Thanks Tobias. Indeed, I missed this `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` but it is not so obvious it has to do with `LaTeX-fill-region` :) I guess there is an extra `\documentclass{article}` in your example code.

Comment: Could you please add in your answer what is the syntax to use in the `.emacs` to add several environments to the `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`? I tried `(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("myverbatimenv" current-indentation))` but that returns "Symbol’s value as variable is void: LaTeX-indent-environment-list".

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using `fancyvrb.sty` to define your custom environment, you only need to hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> and let AUCTeX parse your document.  AUCTeX has a sophisticated style file for `fancyvrb.sty` which takes care of adding your environment to various internal variables.  After that, you can do  <kbd>C-c C-e myverTAB RET</kbd> to include it in your document.  AUCTeX will support the key-value's provided by `fancyvrb.sty` for your environment as well.  This is the file I tested:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myverbatimenv}{Verbatim}{%
  fontsize=\normalsize
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myverbatimenv}[numbers=right]
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{myverbatimenv}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Comment: Some of my custom verbatim environments don't come from `fancyvrb` (e.g. `alltt` from the eponymous package). In fact, the document I'm working on is the French translation of the ["The TeX Live Guide---2020"](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-en/texlive-en.tex?revision=54188&view=markup).